# Setup Reverse DNS with Cpanel and WHM?

Tags: dns, dns-servers, dynamic-dns

I needed to set-up a reverse DNS via cpanel. I followed the steps in this tutorial but it didn't work: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_30/WHMDocs/RdnsForBind.

I use my own name servers registered with go-daddy. But I am with VPS hosting company.

I did use a new serial number and exactly as the tutorial however didnt seems to be working

When I check this via windows

```
nslookup {ip-address}
```

I still get the my hosting company name, when reversed.

Comment: It may take a while to propagate. Does it work now?

Comment: nope is the steps are correct in the article ?

Comment: Which name server is your domain set up to use?

Comment: my own name server .. is this a problem ?

Comment: No. However if you'd left your nameserver pointing at the hosting servers then that would explain why it did't work. It must be something else then.

Answer (score 2):

**Reverse is Typically Handled by Your Provider**

Whoever supplies your IP addresses (usually your hosting provider) MUST either set up your reverse DNS entries on their DNS servers or delegate authority to your nameservers.

For most VPS/hosting providers, they must setup the DNS.

This is due to how reverse DNS lookups happen.

How a reverse DNS lookup is accomplished:

- The DNS resolver reverses the IP, and adds it to ".in-addr.arpa" (or ".ip6.arpa" for IPv6 lookups), turning 192.0.2.25 into 25.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.
- The DNS resolver then looks up the PTR record for 25.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.

  - The DNS resolver asks the root servers for the PTR record for 25.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.
  - The root servers refer the DNS resolver to the DNS servers in charge of the Class A range (192.in-addr.arpa, which covers all IPs that begin with 192).
  - In almost all cases, the root servers will refer the DNS resolver to a "RIR" ("Regional Internet Registry"). These are the organizations that allocate IPs. In general, ARIN handles North American IPs, APNIC handles Asian-Pacific IPs, and RIPE handles European IPs.
  - The DNS resolver will ask the ARIN DNS servers for the PTR record for 25.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.
  - The ARIN DNS servers will refer the DNS resolver to the DNS servers of the organization that was originally given the IP range. These are usually the DNS servers of your ISP, or their bandwidth provider.
  - The DNS resolver will ask the ISP's DNS servers for the PTR record for 25.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.
  - The ISP's DNS servers will refer the DNS resolver to the organization's DNS servers.
  - The DNS resolver will ask the organization's DNS servers for the PTR record for 25.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.
  - The organization's DNS servers will respond with "host.example.com".

Source: http://www.dnsstuff.com/docs/ptr

Answer (score 1):

Is the dns server running on the system?

Edit: As i thought about it longer it does not matter if you set up a reverse dns on you server because your server is not authoritive for the ip address you are trying to change the ptr. This has to be done by the netblock owner. If you get the ip address or addresses changed so your dns is authoritive for that ip then the test will access your servers dns.

Hope that helps

Comment: It is well said because when a ptr request is done, the nameserver from the netblock owner will answer and it will appear as "authority section". The request will never reach your server because it will be answered upfront. Consequently, the PTR records should not be setup in Cpanel but it should be setup by the ISP.